# How do I print an entire vector?

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, vector, printing

I want all items in the vector "listofnums" to print. I tried putting "cout << listofnums[i]" within the for loop thinking it would print each item as it iterated and that didn't work. Putting the cout outside of the loop hasn't worked for me either.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    //variables
    int a, b, i = 0; // a & b inputs, i for iterating
    int likedigits = 0; //counts the number of like digits


    //entering number range
    cout << "Enter the first number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the second number" << endl;
    cin >> b;


    //making a vector to contain numbers between a and b
    vector<int> listofnums((b-a)+1); 
    for (i <= (b-a); i++;) {  
        int initialvalue = a;
        listofnums[i] = initialvalue;                                 
        initialvalue++;                                               
    }


    cout << listofnums << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think you need to take a step back, and go through your class notes or books about `for` loops. Your `for` loop won't do what you probably want it to do. And it won't do what you probably want it to do in more than one way.

Comment: As for printing a vector, there's no standard overload for the output operator `<<` taking a vector (or any other container). Again, you should consult your class notes or books because it should have that information.

Answer (score 3):

For starters the for statement

```
 for (i <= (b-a); i++;) {
```

is written incorrectly. You mean

```
 for ( ;i <= (b-a); i++) {
```

In this (updated) for loop

```
 for ( ;i <= (b-a); i++) {  
    int initialvalue = a;
    listofnums[i] = initialvalue;                                 
    initialvalue++;                                               
}
```

all elements of the vector has the value a because the variable `initialvalue` is defined in each iteration. Place the declaration of the variable outside the ,loop.

```
   int initialvalue = a;
   for (i <= (b-a); i++;) {  
        listofnums[i] = initialvalue;                                 
        initialvalue++;                                               
    }
```

To output the vector you can use for example the range-based for loop

```
for ( const auto &item : listofnums )
{
    std::cout << item << ' ';
}
std::cout << '\n';
```

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 0; 

    std::cout << "Enter the first number: ";
    std::cin >> a;
    std::cout << "Enter the second number: ";
    std::cin >> b;

    std::tie( a, b ) = std::minmax( { a, b } );

    std::vector<int> listofnums( b - a + 1 ); 

    int initialvalue = a;

    for ( auto &item : listofnums ) item = initialvalue++;

    for ( const auto &item : listofnums )
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look the following way

```
Enter the first number: 10
Enter the second number: 5
5 6 7 8 9 10
```

Comment: That got it to print thank you! But now it only prints sets of zeroes..?

Comment: I fixed it by changing my first for loop to a while loop - now it works perfectly thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It works now - with the advice from Vlad from Moscow and changing the first for loop to a while loop:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    //variables
    int a, b, i = 0; // a & b inputs, i for iterating

    //entering number range
    cout << "Enter the first number" << endl;
    cin >> a;
    cout << "Enter the second number" << endl;
    cin >> b;


    //making a vector to contain numbers between a and b
    vector<int> listofnums((b-a)+1); 
    int initialvalue = a;
    while (i <= (b-a)) {  
        listofnums[i] = initialvalue;                                 
        initialvalue++; 
        i++;
    }

    for ( const auto &item : listofnums ){
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }

    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```